# DevExpress Get selected value of ASPxComboBox in ClientSide

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a ASPxGridview that contains a field with ASPxComboBox I want to get the selected value of a ASPxComboBox and display it in a label. In my code below I just store the value on alert() message. But all I'm getting is a "null" value.Can anyone know how to solve my problem? Thank you so much.

**Here's what I have so far**

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" OnRowDataBound="ASPxGridView2_RowDataBound" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="fordtl" KeyFieldName = "chndtl_no">

<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="product" Name="dd_product" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" VisibleIndex="7">
<SettingsHeaderFilter>
<DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
</SettingsHeaderFilter>
<EditItemTemplate>
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBoxProduct" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="avery" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="Product" EnableCallbackMode="true" TextField="pd_product">
<ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { OnProductChanged(s);}"></ClientSideEvents>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function OnProductChanged(s, e) {
   var getProduct = document.getElementById("ASPxComboBoxProduct");
   alert(getProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this in you aspx code -

```
<ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(e,s) { OnProductChanged();}">
</ClientSideEvents>
```

Replace your javascript function from this and check.

```
function OnProductChanged(e, s)
{
      var selectedValue = e.lastSuccessValue;
      alert(selectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your SelectedIndexChanged JS handler to this:

```
function OnProductChanged(s, e) {
   var getProduct = s.GetValue();
   alert(getProduct);
}
```

But if you are to change the label stored elsewhere with a newly selected data, how would you know for which particular grid's row the combobox value was changed?

Comment if this is your requirement, because DX has a way to handle this case.

**UPDATE:**
To be able to differentiate in which row the combobox from EditItemTemplate had selected index changed you need to assign a unique ClientInstanceName for each such combobox. This ClientInstanceName should contain the row index part, for example: `avery_01` .

To be able to accomplish this you need to handle the OnInit event for EACH combobox being displayed and assign ClientInstanceName there like for example the following:

```
...
<EditItemTemplate>
    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBoxProduct" runat="server" 
       OnInit="ASPxComboBoxProduct_Init" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="Product" 
       EnableCallbackMode="true" TextField="pd_product">
    </dx:ASPxComboBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
...
```

Note I have removed the ClientInstanceName attribute and ClientSideEvents element.

Same should be done for your ASPxLabel placed inside ASPxGridView DataItemTemplate:

```
...
<dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Label Column Caption">
<DataItemTemplate>
   <ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel" runat="server" OnInit="ASPxLabel_Init" />
</DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataColumn>
...
```

Then in codebehind you add:

```
// Handle OnInit for each combobox being displayed
protected void ASPxComboBoxProduct_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
    ASPxComboBox dvxCombo = (ASPxComboBox)sender;
    GridViewDetailRowTemplateContainer templateContainer =
                   (GridViewDetailRowTemplateContainer)ASPxGridView2.NamingContainer;
    dvxCombo.ClientInstanceName = string.Format("avery_{0}",
                                             templateContainer.VisibleIndex);

    // below client instance name should set for the relevant label in the labels 
    //own OnInit handler below
    string targetLabelClientInstanceName = string.Format("label_{0}",
                                             templateContainer.VisibleIndex);
    // Note, we're passing the ASPxLabel's ClientInstanceName as a third
    // param to the SelectedIndexChanged event handler.
    dvxCombo.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = 
        string.Format("function(s, e) {{ OnProductChanged(s, e, {0}); }}",
        targetLabelClientInstanceName);        
}


// Handle OnInit for each ASPxLabel which you will be updating with the
// selected combobox value
protected void ASPxLabel_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ASPxLabel dvxLabel = (ASPxLabel)sender;
    GridViewDetailRowTemplateContainer templateContainer =
                   (GridViewDetailRowTemplateContainer)ASPxGridView2.NamingContainer;
    dvxLabel.ClientInstanceName = string.Format("label_{0}",
                                             templateContainer.VisibleIndex);    
}
```

Then update you JavaScript handler like this:

```
function OnProductChanged(s, e, label) {
   var getProduct = s.GetValue();
   alert(getProduct);

   label.SetText(getProduct);
}
```

Note, above the `label` is not just a string or jQuery object, it's real DevExpress client side object for the ASPxLabel defined in another grid column on the same row as the current combobox for which this event will be handled. Therefore it should all DX client side methods like SetText() and GetText.

So the above approach has been verified to work. Note, all code snippets I've typed in directly without compiling. But I trust you should be able to glue them all around.

Similar cases:

1. [Checking if a aspxgridview Master-Detail has any row checked in Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514338/checking-if-a-aspxgridview-master-detail-has-any-row-checked-in-client-side)
2. [https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q372498](http://ASPxGridView%20-%20How%20to%20get%20editor%20inside%20EditItemTemplate%20via%20ClientInstanceName)

HTH

Comment: Yes I'm going to store the value in label soon. And I have 3 more dropdown. Do you have any idea on how to know which is the selected value has changed? Thank you.

Comment: @x'tian I have provided samples how to corretly handle your case. If the above was helpful I would appreciate answer accept and vote up. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the sample. I'm just confuse what if I want to store the value in dropdown? I mean the value of the second dropdown is base on the selected value of first dropdown, just like cascading. But would gladly want to try your sample first. Thank you. :)

Comment: Hi Im getting this error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxLabel'."

Comment: in the second column where you have your 'label' did you define it as DIV or as APSxLabel? Do you still need to update the label when the combobox value changes or do you try to update another combobox? Add the complete grid mark up to the question text pls.

Comment: It is also inside the gridview where the combobox is placed. I just want to achieve this one https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/gridediting/cascadingcomboboxes.aspx. Wherein the second combobox value is base on the first combobox. But I want it in much easier why cause I find it a bit complicated if I follow the demo in edvexpress. Thank you so much. I hope you can teach me the easier way to achieve this. :)

Comment: so how is your label defined? Is it in the same cell or the next cell to the combobox? add the relevant .aspx grid markup to the ticket.

Comment: it is the next cell and it is actually a combobox not a label.   I just think of a work around to store the first combobox into a label and get the value of that label and store it on the second combobox. If you're about to follow my workaround scenario the label is outside the gridview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134540/discussion-between-andrews-and-xtian).

Comment: @x'tian I've seen 2 ur last messages in chat...I also checked the DX sample. Do you also have comboboxes appearing only after you click the Edit link? If yes, then my approach wont work out of the box. It would work if you had comboboxes ALWAYS visible, so they should not be put in EditItemTemplate but in DataItemTemplate.

Comment: oh really? Ok just try it to put in dataItemTemplate I thought it wouldn't matter. Sorry I am a DX newbie.

Comment: Would you mind to provide me another sample corresponding the two combo boxes inside the grid?

Comment: could you login again in chat room?

Comment: @x'tian I'm in. Use this link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134540/discussion-between-andrews-and-xtian

Answer (score 0):

Label will be updated while combobox changed event but it will lost it's value on post back. Avoid post back on combobox index change then label will be updated as you need.

```
AutoPostBack="false"
```